# Is it possible to get notifications for specific email senders?

Tags: notifications, email

I just want push notifications when my boss sends me email.

Comment: This will probably depend on the email app you're using and possibly your email provider.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the solutions mentioned in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12033/email-application-with-notifications-only-for-specified-contacts-standard-smtp/33946#33946). Otherwise we're need more details on what kind of email and phone setup you have.